# Rename/rewrite php urls with htaccess or anyother methods

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to change/rewrite urls from "https://www.example.com/stats/domain/report/1/google.com" to "https://www.example.com/stats/1/google.com" or "https://www.example.com/stats/google.com"?

Value 1 and google.com gathered from MYSQL. It is just like imitating urls from db row id. Those are dynamic urls from laravel framework.

Anyone give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

I have tried basic htaccess rewrite methods. But nothing helps with the dynamic url pattern.

Comment: Do you really need to use .htaccess for URL rewriting in your specific scenario? Is there a particular reason for this choice? Because best way to achieve this is to use Laravel's built-in routing system.